# Question on finding formula for a Sequences

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Hello would appreciate any help, the sequence is given below

$y_0 = 1,\,y_1= 2y_0+1 = 2+1 = 3,\,y_2= 2y_1+1 = 2^2 + 2 + 1 = 7,\,y_3= 2y_2 +1 = 2^3 +2^2 +2 +1 = 15$

The question is

What is the general expression for the sequence $y_t$ in terms of t ?

$y_t = 2^t + 2^{t-1} + .... 2^2 + 2 + 1 $

which suggests

$y_t = 1 +2 + 2^2 + ... + 2^{t-1} + 2^t$

I have no idea how they got $y_t$ ? can anyone help

Comment: Hint: since $y_{n+1}=2\,y_n+1\,$ search the corresponding recurrence for $x_n:=y_n+1$. Deduce the general formula for $x_n$.

Comment: thanks, what is the difference beetween 'General formula' and yn+1 formula ?

Comment: $y_{n+1}=g(y_n,y_{n-1},\cdots)\,$ is a recurrence ; $t_n=f(n)$ is a 'general formula' or expression of whatever. The recurrence for $x_n$ should be simple enough to deduce the general formula.

Comment: Sorry im still confused, the entire chapter is about how to find the sum of a sequence and this section has thrown me off.
I understand the sequence goes 1,3,7 etc
how do I use that information to get 

$y_t = 2^t + 2^{t-1} + .... 2^2 + 2 + 1 $

Comment: Are you familiar with the idea of [Mathematical Induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction)

Comment: Another hint use [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) to rewrite  $\;y_t = 2^t + 2^{t-1} + .... 2^2 + 2 + 1\,$ as $2^{t+1}-1$.

Comment: no sorry,
I thought perhaps if I sub in t=1,2,3 I would get the orginal sequence but instead I get 
t=1        y1 = 2
t=2        y2= 1
?

Comment: Can you perhaps direct me to an easier example so I can understand the conccept ?
Are you suggesting I use the sum of the first n terms formula ?
my a=1 and my r = 2t ?

Comment: In fact this is one of the easiest example so consider only my second hint and *think* at what you obtained.

Comment: Im still confused ?

Comment: In case of confusion changing the point of view may help. If your point of view is global try for example to consider my derivations at a very low level (say by rederiving everything by hand...). If your confusion comes from the abstract $n$ replace it by a fixed value and so on. If confusions remain after all this ask very specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use the two methods proposed in the comments :

1. Since $\,y_{n+1}=2\,y_n+1\,$ we have $\,y_{n+1}+1=2\,(y_n+1)\,$ and thus 
   $$y_{n+1}+1=2\,(2\,(y_{n-1}+1))=\cdots=2^n(y_1+1)=2^{n+2}$$
   from $\,y_{n+1}=2^{n+2}-1\,$ we conclude that  $\,\boxed{y_{n}=2^{n+1}-1}$.
2. You observed that for $k\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ we had $\,y_k=1+2^1+2^2+\cdots+2^k\,$ but this is a geometric progression and thus you got (expand the product to convince you) : $$y_k=(2-1)(1+2^1+2^2+\cdots+2^k)=2^{k+1}-1$$
   To prove that this is true for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ suppose that $y_n=2^{n+1}-1\,$ and use $\,y_{n+1}=2\,y_n+1\,$ to obtain the same formula for $n+1$ :
   $$y_{n+1}=2\,(2^{n+1}-1)+1=2^{(n+1)+1}-1$$
   Since the relation $y_n=2^{n+1}-1\,$ holds for (say) $n=0$ we proved (by [induction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) as proposed by rightskewed) that it will remain true for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Hoping this clarified things,